# Better way to set cell

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, tableview, cell

I started writing my first apps using MVC, and i dont know with code version is better on this pattern.

In viewcontroller:

```
 let quantity = quantityProducts[indexPath.row]
 let nameProduct = productsArray[indexPath.row]
 cell.configurateWithItem(quantity: quantity, name: nameProduct)
```

In cellClass:

```
class NeedProductsTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var quantityLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var productNameLabel: UILabel!

func configurateWithItem(quantity:String,name:String){
    quantityLabel.text = quantity
    quantityLabel.textColor = .systemGray
    quantityLabel.font = quantityLabel.font.withSize(14)
    productNameLabel.text = name
    productNameLabel.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 14)
}
```

or maybe standard verion (set cell properties in view controller)?

```
  let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "NeedProductsTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! NeedProductsTableViewCell
        cell.quantityLabel.text = quantityProducts[indexPath.row]
        cell.quantityLabel.textColor = .systemGray
        cell.quantityLabel.font = cell.quantityLabel.font.withSize(14)
        cell.productNameLabel.text = productsArray[indexPath.row]
        cell.productNameLabel.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 14)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer might be opinion based but I can really see no arguments toward using the second "standard version" approach.

This goes beyond MVC but you should keep your public interface as closed as possible, only expose properties that make sense. So use `private` in most cases.

So in your cell I suggest

```
@IBOutlet private var quantityLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet private var productNameLabel: UILabel!
```

You may persist `weak` though it is not needed. You could also use optionals instead of force-unwrapped values `quantityLabel: UILabel?` instead of `quantityLabel: UILabel!` to improve stability.

So once you have internal parts private you need to check how to expose your interface. This still has multiple patterns; one is what you used, your cell does not save the object you inject but just modifies its visual representation. The other one would look like this:

```
class NeedProductsTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet private var quantityLabel: UILabel?
@IBOutlet private var productNameLabel: UILabel?

var item: (quantity: String, name: String)? {
    didSet {
        if let item = item {
            quantityLabel?.text = item.quantity
            quantityLabel?.textColor = .systemGray
            quantityLabel?.font = quantityLabel.font.withSize(14)
            productNameLabel?.text = item.name
            productNameLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 14)
        }        
    }
}
```

In this case you would use in your data source:

```
cell.item = (quantityProducts[indexPath.row], productsArray[indexPath.row])
```

This also suggests that you should have only 1 array if possible. Either using a structure to encapsulate both values or to simply use tuples:

```
private var items: [(quantity: String, name: String)] = []
```

instead of

```
private var quantityProducts: [String] = []
private var productsArray: [String] = []
```

Comment: `theLabels?.font`; & `theLabels.textColor` should be set in the init, no? Depending on how is created the cell awakeFromNib or init(style)

Comment: @Larme Agreed. I thought that at first as well. But maybe the OP is planning to have an `else` somewhere in there (or another configure-with) method that sets other fonts or text colors. In that case this is placed correctly. I was thinking in `awakeFromNib` but then why not just set them up correctly in Storyboard, right?

Comment: Thanks for answer. I must have two arrayData, becouse I parse bigger dataModel using json parsing. Thanks for gives me other way to set properties, but now i dont know whose type is better, using func or var item.

Comment: @Triker the "whose type is better" is opinion based or even depends on the scenario. The property is better when you need to use it later on (For instance you add a "Like" button on cell that holds `Post` object. Then when clicked you can say `self.post.like()` inside the cell). In other hand if you have multiple configure-with situations then it is best to use this approach; Imagine `configureWith(person: Person)` and `configureWith(happyThought: HappyThought)` at the same time.

Comment: ok, it works like I thought, well in this case i used func, but i will use your way in another view, because i refactoring all my cell. Really thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the **Single responsibility** principle the best thing you can do is not to have the `delegate` of the `UITableView` to your `UIViewController` and to have a new class called YourTableViewController: UITableViewController and assign that class to your tableView in the storyboard.

Now your `UIViewController` handles the `UIViewController` issues, `UITableView` class handles the `UITableView` issues, and everything that has to do with the `UITableViewCell` is being handled by the `CustomUITableViewCell` class.

So the best is to call the `configurateWithItem()` function after you create your cell but from your `UITableView` custom class.

By following this rule you keep your `UIViewControllers` small and you don't create **Massive View Controllers**. Also `UITableViewControllers` can be reused in different `UIViewControllers`.